# Change value of a label when select form is changed with jQuery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

What I want to do is to be able to change the value of a label when I make a change in a dropdown select form.

```
<select form="FormCalcInput" id="calcOption" title="Choose what value you want to count> 
    <option value="PMT" class="PMT">Payment (PMT)</option>
    <option value="I" class="I">Interest (I)</option>
    <option value="FV" class="FV">Future value (FV)</option>
    <option value="PV" class="PV">Present value (PV)</option>
</select>

<label id="labelChanged"></label>
```

So the label should be the previous selected value.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't get it? When you select `Interest (I)`, the label should say `"Payment"`, and when you select `Future Value (FV)` the label should say ... wait for it .... `"Payment"`? What's the logic!

Comment: @adeneo oh sorry for not being so clear. What i meant is that the label should be the previous selected value.

Comment: @Dave previous selected value or the current selected value? Update your question to be clear

Comment: Previous, as the one selected before this one, or the previous option in the DOM, it's not really clear what you're asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the previous selected, you need a global variable :

```
var newLabel = '';
$('#calcOption').on('change', function(){
    $('#labelChanged').text(newLabel); //Change the text before changing the value
    switch(this.value){
        case 'I':
            newLabel = 'Interest';
            break;
        case 'FV':
            newLabel = 'Future value';
            break;
        case 'PV':
            newLabel = 'Present value';
            break;
        case 'PMT':
            newLabel = 'Payment';
            break;
    }
}).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var previous = $('#calcOption').val();
    $('#calcOption').change(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();

        $('#labelChanged').html(previous);
        previous = val;
    });
});
```

Updated

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. I know its kind of a beginner question but you got to start somewhere :) @user3441954

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it should be like this.

```
$('#calcOption').on('change', function() {
    var prev = $(this).data('prev') || $('option:first', this).text();

    $('#labelChanged').text(prev);
    $(this).data('prev', $('option:selected', this).text());
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vqxRa/)

This saves the previously selected value and sets it as the labels text

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but this sets the label to the text from the option selected

```
$('#calcOption').on('change', function(){
    var v = $(this).find(':selected').text();
    $('#labelChanged').text( v );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zQ77t/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<select form="FormCalcInput" id="calcOption" title="Choose what value you want to count" onChange="changelabel(this.value)"> 
<option value="PMT" class="PMT">Payment (PMT)</option>
<option value="I" class="I">Interest (I)</option>
<option value="FV" class="FV">Future value (FV)</option>
<option value="PV" class="PV">Present value (PV)</option>
</select>

<label id="labelChanged"></label>
```

in javascript

```
var labelname;
function changelabel(var value){
     switch(value){
         case 'I': 
         case 'FV':
             labelname  = 'Payments';
             break;
         case 'PMT':
     }
  $('#labelChanged').html(labelname);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
function TestFunction() {

                var name = $("#calcOption option:selected").text();

                if (name == "Interest (I)") {
                    $("#labelChanged").val("");
                    $("#labelChanged").text("Payment");
                }
                else if (name == "Interest (I)") {
                  //set other value
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call this kind of code on change event of dropDown

```
Var ddlSelectedValue = $('#calcOption').text();
$('#labelChanged').text(ddlSelectedValue );
```